# On a recursive functional equation of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am trying to prove the following functional equation:

$$
\frac{ζ(s)}{ζ(1 − s)} = −s \frac{\tan(\frac{πs}{2})ζ(1 + s)}{2πζ(−s)},
$$

where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function for $s\in\mathbb{C}$, and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

I tried using Riemann's functional equation:

$$
ζ(s) = 2^s π^{s−1}\sin(\frac{πs}{2})Γ(1 − s)ζ(1 − s),
$$

and by the substitution $s\to1-s$ quickly derived:

$$
ζ(1 − s) = 2 (2π)^{-s}\cos(\frac{πs}{2})Γ(s)ζ(s).
$$

However, I am stuck at this point, as no matter how I combine these two equations I never get the functional equation in my question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see why this isn't a question about $\zeta(s)$ nor analytic number theory ?

Comment: @reuns Yes. But at the time of writing of the question, I wasn't sure whether I needed to use some "analytic number theory" trick to get to the solution.

Comment: @reuns I don't understand the purpose of your comment.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ has been studied intensively for a century, everything is in the books.

Comment: @reuns You could post that as an answer to every question concerning analytic number theory. This site is for people who do not have experience with reading all the books of the last century on the subject.

Comment: That's why you should read those books and ask about what you don't understand

Comment: @reuns I am not a mathematician. I don't have time to read tens or possibly more books after 8 hours of work every day. Which is why, when I have a question, I ask a Question-Answer forum such as this one.

Comment: It doesn't change that the useful results and methods about $\zeta(s)$ are in those books, not elsewhere..

Comment: @reuns Again, I don't understand the purpose of your comment(s). They are not aimed to help my current question. I have bought and are reading through the books by Edwards and Ivic (which by the way is far from an easily digested material for me), but as I said these books take a lot of time after work. As you can see, I am looking "in those books", but when I have a question I ask it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also know that $\zeta(-s) = -2^{-s}\pi^{-s-1}\sin (\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1+s)\zeta(1+s)$ and $\zeta(1+s) = 2(2\pi)^s \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(-s)\zeta(-s)$.

So, we have: $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = \frac{1}{\pi} (2\pi)^s \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(1-s) \tag{1}$$

We also know that by property of the gamma function: $\Gamma(c)c = \Gamma(1+c)$.

Thus, $\Gamma(1-s) = (-s)\Gamma(-s)$. So, $(1)$ becomes: $$\frac{1}{\pi}(-s)(2\pi)^s\sin (\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(-s) =-2s(2\pi)^{s-1}\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(-s)$$ $$=-\frac{s}{2\pi} \tan(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \frac{\zeta(1+s)}{\zeta(-s)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please elaborate a bit more on the final step?

Comment: @Pickle From my first sentence, we know $$\frac{\zeta(1+s)}{\zeta(-s)} = 2(2\pi)^s \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(-s)$$ Do some manipulation and you are done!